# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for a jar being imported into spring boot project

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I had created a jar and it works fine as a spring boot project ,but when I want to import that as a dependency and use it , a test controller gives me  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException  exception .

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.xyz.digital.iotgtw.iridium.exceptions.GetSubscriberAccountException;
import com.xyz.digital.iotgtw.iridium.model.GetSubscriberAccountResponseImpl;
import com.xyz.digital.iotgtw.iridium.services.IridiumService;

    @RestController
    public class controller {
        
        @Autowired
        IridiumService IridiumService;
        
        @GetMapping
        public String getData() throws GetSubscriberAccountException {
            
            GetSubscriberAccountResponseImpl x =IridiumService.getSubscriberAccount("some value");
            
            return "hello";
        }
  
    }
```

The Iridium jar is imported as a dependency ,the jar also has been created by me which basically calls this party apis  .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xyz.digital</groupId>
    <artifactId>iridium</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Let me if what could be the possible reasons for this jar being not loaded at runtime .Logic in jar works fine . I tested using test methods .

Comment: What packages are scanned for components?

Comment: Two assumptions: 1) your app doesn't scan "com.xyz.digital" package 2) IridiumService is not a bean.

Comment: okay let me try  to scan packages

Comment: on  scanning package com.xyz.digital, was able to proced from the previous error ,but  I have few placeholders in the jar which should be picked from properties file but are giving Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder